# Is there difference between Fusion and Hybrid?

Tags: terminology

In Music Terminology is there difference between **Fusion** and **Hybrid**?

I was reading a [text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_music) about [Rock music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_music). I bring it here to clarify my question.

> By the late 1960s a number of distinct rock music sub-genres had emerged, including **hybrids** like blues rock, folk rock, country rock, ... .
>
> Further **fusion** sub-genres have since emerged, including pop punk, rap rock, and rap metal, ... .

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question, seems like a perfectly valid one to me...

Comment: Oh, damn, a zombie question.  Never mind then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that "hybrid" is not a musical term. The author is simply using it here according to its typical dictionary definition:

> **hy•brid** `|ˈhīˌbrid|`
>   noun
>   a thing made by combining two different elements; a mixture

**["Fusion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_%28music%29)** has extensive musical connotations, however. In general it means the same thing as hybrid, but you would use it to refer to a distinctive sub-genre that resulted from the merging of two other genres of music.

Additionally, **[Jazz Fusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jazz_fusion)** is a topic in and of itself--the linked Wikipedia article is an excellent overview of the genesis and history of the genre, which was initially defined by such influential artists as [Miles Davis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Davis), [Herbie Hancock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbie_Hancock), and [Jaco Pastorius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaco_Pastorius).

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not a meaningful question. I've never heard the term "hybrid" applied like you are using it. Perhaps you should cite your source: what is the name of the author of that text, and where is it from?

"Hybrid" is a term that comes from horticulture, or plant breeding, such as when two different varieties of rose are crossed to make a new variety of rose.

"Fusion" is a term that means taking two things and fusing them together. Although it probably goes back farther than that, it was applied by some journalists in the late 1960s and 1970s to describe music that blended the styles of jazz and rock.

Your writer is just talking about pieces of music that display characteristics of multiple styles of music combined. That is all.